# Which m2eclipse archetype to use for JBoss/Hibernate based projects?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, archetypes, project-settings

I am new to Java world but I am pretty good at using Flex, actionscript 3, Ant and even Maven to some extent. Now I would like to learn some java and use Hibernate and JBoss (webapp).

I already have Maven working and have found the m2eclipse plugin on the web, it seem pretty nice for maven integration.

Now I would like to know how to set the project using "best practices" if possible and start the ball rolling. My question is not about using Java or Hibernate, it is just about project settings / configuration using m2eclipse or maybe another tool if necessary.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, [archetypes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List) are not m2eclipse specific, they are maven species. But this was just a side note. Now, to answer your question, there is "sadly" no unique option and I hope I won't make things more confusing at listing them:

- You could simply use the `maven-archetype-webapp` archetype to create a blank webapp and setup the Hibernate stuff yourself (follow the [Hibernate tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-webapp) which is maven based).
- You could create a more specialized webapp (using the `struts2-archetype-starter` or the `wicket-archetype-quickstart` or a MyFaces archetype) and setup the Hibernate stuff yourself.
- You could use the [`javaee5-maven-archetype`](http://code.google.com/p/javaee5-maven-archetype/) archetype to create a Java EE 5 (JSF 1.2 + EJB 3) application.
- You could use the `softeu-archetype-seam` archetype to create a JBoss Seam application (JSF+Facelets+Seam).
- You could use one of the numerous [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/) archetypes (Hibernate, Spring and the presentation framework of your choise) to create an "AppFuse" application.

If you want some guidance, my recommendation would be to go for an [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/) archetype.
Choose a presentation framework and pick up the corresponding archetype. If you want a more "naked" solution, generate a blank webapp and setup hibernate yourself (follow the mentioned tutorial).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I am playing with maven-archetype-webapp for the moment :)

Comment: @AdnanDoric That's a good choice IMO. BTW: The common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;)